# Layout problems (php,html)

Tags: php

I made some images which i need, currently i have :

```
    $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td align='center'><b>{$name}</b></td>       </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align='center'><img src='$avatar'/></td>  </tr>
                  <td align='center'><b>Points</b>: {$points}</td> </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td align='center'><b>Status</b>:<b><font color='green'> {$misc['text_status']}</font></b></td>  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td align='center'><a href='".$link."'><font color='red'><b>See more statistics</b></font></a><hr></td></tr>

            ";
```

with script i get this(ie image) http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/7885/thisdn.png  .
Now i need to output something like this http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/171/thatq.png (ie image) without mysql. May i have some examples of yours?

Comment: This HTML is wrong on so many levels. `font` is deprecated and using tables for layout is a bad habit. It's going to cause serious problems if you ever need to change the layout.

Answer (score 4):

move `<tr>` before your for loop and `</tr>` after you for loop

or better one, place individual tables with `float:left` for each member

Answer (score 1):

You could try to wrap every profile information (photo, points etc) in a div and not use tables at all. Then float these div-s to the right or left. Note that every div must have the same class.